# PoppupWindow from Bottom?

Tags: android

I need a very simple thing i just dont know the Views that i need for it, maybe a PopupWindow?

So this is what i want:
If the user tap on the button, a popup window should slide up from the bottom, exactly the same way as in the picture:
http://adamvarhegyi.atw.hu/popped.png

So it should be stay at the bottom of the screen, and it should not be full screened.

Anyone can help me to do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html lets you define animations that will allow you to translate your custom view.

Comment: And what view should i use for it?

Comment: a general view object can have an animation, your probably looking at a relative layout that you populate

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about a menu button?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    menu.add(0, MENU_ID, 0, R.string.export).setShortcut('1', 'e');
```